# libvirt virsh not using a predefined target while attaching interface

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, virsh

I am trying to automate the process of creating a Guest VM. I am using [uvt-kvm](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/uvt-kvm.1.html#:%7E:text=uvt%2Dkvm%20is%20carefully%20constructed,not%20%22special%22%20in%20libvirt.) to create the VM. I am also taking a network type as a parameter. This can be either `nat` or `macvtap`.

Now in the script I create the macvtap interface using these steps:

```
MACVTAP_INTERFACE="macvtap$VM_NAME"
ip link add link eno1 name $MACVTAP_INTERFACE type macvtap mode bridge
ip link set $MACVTAP_INTERFACE up
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev $MACVTAP_INTERFACE
```

The MACVTAP interface with the same name is created without issues. Then I try to attach it to the guest VM which is already created and shutdown in the script before this step. I tried two ways of attaching it:

```
Way 1:

virsh attach-interface $VM_NAME --type direct --source eno1 --mode bridge --model virtio --target $MACVTAP_INTERFACE --config
```

This does not actually attach the interface I created before but rather creates a new interface like `macvtap11` and attaches it to the VM. Although source, mode and model are set, the target is still not set.

```
Way 2:

cat > interface-{$VM_NAME}.xml << EOF
  <interface type='direct'>
    <source dev="eno1" mode="bridge"/>
    <model type='virtio'/>
    <target dev="$MACVTAP_INTERFACE"/>
  </interface>
EOF

  virsh attach-device $VM_NAME interface-{$VM_NAME}.xml --persistent --config
  rm interface-{$VM_NAME}.xml
```

This also results in the same thing. Creates a new interface and attaches it to the VM and doesn't take `<target dev="$MACVTAP_INTERFACE"/>` into consideration.

This is the XML from a VM which I created using virt-manager UI:

```
<interface type="direct">
  <mac address="52:54:00:58:03:46"/>
  <source dev="eno1" mode="bridge"/>
  <target dev="macvtap9"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>
```

I made sure all parameters remain same when I attach my interface to the new VM.

Please help me out with how I can define a custom interface and attach it to the VM. The same solution should also work for NAT as well.

Also I am assigning a public IP address subnet while creating the MACVTAP interface. However, my guest VM is not getting a public IP when I use `ip addr show`. When I create the VM with a MACVTAP interface in `virt-manager`, it does assign the public IP. I think it is not a DHCP issue or else virt-manager should not have been able to assign the IP either.